# Get a working toolbar in a UIPickerView Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uipickerview, uitoolbar

So I have a textfield that uses a pickerview. But for some reason as of iOS 11.x it doesn't seem to show up. I can't seem to figure out why. I have looked at some of the other questions and it seems my implementation is the same, yet the toolbar does not appear on loading the picker view. 
Below is the code where I declare and set the toolbar for the pickerview :

```
let picker: UIPickerView
    picker = UIPickerView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 200, width: view.frame.width, height: 300))



    picker.showsSelectionIndicator = true
    picker.delegate = self
    picker.dataSource = self


    let toolBar = UIToolbar()
    toolBar.barStyle = UIBarStyle.default
    toolBar.isTranslucent = false
    toolBar.tintColor = UIColor(red: 76/255, green: 217/255, blue: 100/255, alpha: 1)
    toolBar.sizeToFit()


    let doneButton = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Done", style: UIBarButtonItemStyle.plain, target: self, action: #selector(UploadViewController.donePicker))
    let spaceButton = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: UIBarButtonSystemItem.flexibleSpace, target: nil, action: nil)

    toolBar.setItems([spaceButton, doneButton], animated: false)
    toolBar.isUserInteractionEnabled = true

    requestTextField.inputView = picker
    requestTextField.inputAccessoryView = toolBar
```

Comment: If you are going to call `sizeToFit` on the toolbar, do it after setting its items.

Comment: @KSigWyatt Thanks, that was it. If you make this an answer I will select it as the correct one.

Comment: @aegeus24 Great to hear!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to make sure that you declare `translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false` or else any constraints you set won't work.

Also it doesn't look like you have any constraints. But before you can add constraints to the view make sure that the view is added to the parent - if this is not done either through storyboards or using `view.addSubView(picker)` the constraints will cause your app to crash.

Use this example to add constraints to your view.
`picker.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.leadingAnchor)`

In addition, use `view.leadingAnchor` for the left constraint and `view.trailingAnchor` for the right instead of `view.frame.width` for the width of your `UIPicker`